# Java - Add message to inbox

Tags: java, email

How add message to inbox folder from java app? Right now to do this i use the same FROM and TO addresses (javamail -> smtp). Mail server is remote (Exchange), so i cant get access to it file system.

Answer (score 0):

If your mail server is Exchange 2007 or Higher, I'd look into [EWSJavaAPI](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) Microsoft made a nice interface to all of the Exchange Web Services calls (no messing with dirty dirty SOAP)